# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::handle() in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I was trying to run an insert query into my Database then get 
this error .

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::handle();
```

can anyone explain what the error means

this is what my query looks like.

```
$jobrequest = new jobrequest;

       $jobrequest->job_title = $request->job_title ;
       $jobrequest->job_describe = $request->job_describe ;
       $jobrequest->artisans = $request->artisans ;
       $jobrequest->budget = $request->budget ;
       $jobrequest->user_fullname = $request->user_fullname ;
       $jobrequest->user_mobilenum = $request->user_mobilenum ;
       $jobrequest->user_email = $request->user_email ;
       $jobrequest->user_city = $request->user_city ;
       $jobrequest->detailed_add = $request->detailed_address;


       $jobrequest->job_email = $request->user_email ;

       $jobrequest->save();
       $request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');

         return redirect()->route('Views');
```